# Mockito Using doAnswer on Spy

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to use when(spy).thenAnswer(new Answer()) 
But It seems that thenAnswer working only on mock and not on spy.
I want to use spy as I only want to stub particular method.

Is there a way to do answer on spy object ?

Answer (score 10):

As stated in the offical [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy), it is possible and sometimes even advised:

> **Important gotcha on spying real objects!**
>
> Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use when(Object) for stubbing spies. Therefore when using spies please consider
>   doReturn|Answer|Throw() family of methods for stubbing.

But, once again as the [doc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer%28org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29) states:

> Stubbing voids requires different approach from when(Object) because
>   the compiler does not like void methods inside brackets...

Is your method void?

Example from the documentation if void:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        Mock mock = invocation.getMock();
        return null;
    }
}).when(mock).someMethod();
```

Thus, you should use the following code if your method is void:

```
MyObject spy = spy(myObject);

doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return null;
    }
}).when(spy).notify();
```

Or if it is not void:

```
when(spy.toString()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return "this";
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't wrote it but off course I use a method when(spy.method()).thenAnswer(new Answer())

Comment: And is your method() void or does it return something?

Comment: This answer saved me... I was struggling since yesterday trying to figure out why when().then(answer); ... It was a headache... I just tried doAnswer().when() and it works perfect...

Answer (score 6):

After looking at your code I found the problem 
When using spy we need to use

```
doAnswer.(new Answer<T>() {..}).when(spy).method()
```

And NOT !!!

```
when(spy.method()).thenAnswer(new Answer<T>() {..})
```

Thanks

Comment: notice that My method is with parameters spy.method(arg)